# Java bytecode instrumentation to a method identified by ASPECTJ

Tags: java, aspectj, instrumentation

I have a legacy java code that I currently cannot modify/don't have access to it's source code.
We found out that there's a problem with all methods that have a runtime annotation called @SomeAnnotation, and we would like to fix something inside these methods.

```
@SomeAnnotation
void someMethod(...) {
     ...

}
```

I know that I can use AOP (aspectJ) to catch all functions with these annotation and add operations before/after, as well as replacing the execution code with something else... But what I'd like to do is to add something inside this function and leaving the rest of the code as is (scan the bytecode and modify the function in the middle...)

Is it possible to do that? If so - how?

Thanks

Comment: I had done this through `javap -verbose` to view java class for finding my code which I want to edit it, and edit it by vim with command `:%!xxd`. I was  luck for that work.

Comment: @xxxzhi thanks. I don't want to manually modify the files with vim. I want to inject the code automatically.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly do you want to replace? A method call? The end result? What do those methods have in common that you want to replace/repair? Please give an example as concrete as possible. Then I can tell you if AspectJ is capable of doing it. Specific answers require specific questions. The old principle applies: garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: I will only know at runtime what to replace, when the app is loaded I get a file with the method calls to replace. Aspectj can't do that AFAIK, unless there is a way to manipulate byte code within. I cannot create the method adpects in advanced, I only know in which function they are located...(the one with the annotation)

Answer (score 1):

You can try  [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) - It is a class library for editing bytecodes in Java; it enables Java programs to define a new class at runtime and to modify a class file when the JVM loads it.

Or
[HotSwap](http://www.hotswapagent.org/quick-start) - It allows changing method body, add/rename a method/field

Also you might find [this link](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/practical-introduction-into-code-injection-with-aspectj-javassist-and-java-proxy/) useful.

(Depending on what you need to do (add some code at the beginning, do the rest of the function, add some code at the end, and not modify the function right in the middle), you might be able to use an around advice, with a `ProceedingJoinPoint invocation`
 as a parameter, you can execute your code and then call `invocation.proceed()`  to delegate the call to the original target.)

Comment: Thanks @laura, I know I can do it with javassist and reviewing all the classes and all the byte code - but I really wanted to avoid that and use a tool that such as aspectJ that will let me do it without going over all the classes by myself. The main problem is that I need to replace something in the middle of a function (otherwise it would have been simple with AOP). HotSwap will allow me to replace a method with a method, not to manipulate an existing one AFAIK. Seems that there is no way other than going over all the bytecode to achieve what I want (or use a de-compiler...)